# Can Windows Phone Support Java

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm Windows Phone Developer, and I have a basic query about whether Windows Phone is supporting Java. And if it is supported - how to install jar files in wp7 device?

Because I have read an article about installing jar files in Windows Mobile on this link  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-java-windows-mobile/.

So out of curiosity I just want to raise a query about WP7 compatibility with Java. 
I just hope I'll getting answer from you guys.

Comment: Windows Phone is completely different thing than Windows Mobile.
Both are coming from Microsoft and both are phone OS, but they are completely different in terms of architecture an capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone doesn't support Java in any way. Windows Phone only "executes" xap files and XNA files in any version (7.0 or higher).

No way to run Java in Windows Phone. Isn't useful, too. ;)

Comment: XNA and Silverlight apps are **both** packaged as XAPs, so there is no such thing as "XNA files" when it comes to shipping the product.

Comment: Yes Den. As you said ;)